# Relative side lengths of dual dodecahedron and icosahedron

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polyhedra

If the side length of a dodecahedron is $1$, then what is the side length of its dual icosahedron whose vertices occupy the same space as the mid-points of the faces of the dodecahedron.  I've read that the answer to this is $1.618$ (golden ratio).  But my calculations make it $1.1708$ ($\tan 54^\circ\times\sin 58.2825^\circ$ [half the dihedral angle]).  I've even made paper models and my version looks OK.  If I make the icosahedron with side lengths of $1.618$ then there's no way it will fit inside the dodecahedron.  What am I not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

What they are doing is having the edges of the dual figures bisect each other. As a result, the vertices of the icosahedron and the dodecahedron together make up the vertices of a rhombic triacontahedron, I will get a picture: alright, see [HHEERRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_triacontahedron)  where, in the lower right of the page, they show:

> A rhombic triacontahedron with an inscribed dodecahedron (blue) and
>   icosahedron (purple). (Click here for rotating model)

You can do this yourself, make 30 rhombususeses with diagonal ratio = $\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}$ out of cardboard, put it together, then you can draw the figures in one color each.

Two inexpensive books I have that I can recommend, [Daud Sutton](http://www.walkerbooks.com/books/catalog.php?key=240) and [Alan Holden](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486268519.html)

Comment: Thank you - this is very helpful.  It looks like the side length of the icosahedron can vary (ie. not always golden ratio) depending on how much it bisects the dodecahedron.  The question I was given says "occupy the same space" so I think that means no bisection at all - the vertices of the icosahedron sit exactly on the mid-point of the faces of the dodecahedron, so I think my calculation is right then.  Thanks for your explanation.  sue